# multiple servlet entries in web.xml tomcat

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

here is the code of my web.xml. it has two servlets mapped to different urls. if i am putting only one url at a time there it is working fine for both servlets. but putting them together in xml is always invoking "loginpage" servlet even if the request is "http://localhost:8181/servlet_jsp/loginauth" for "loginauth".

i know i can use alternative like annotation, but my curiosity is, why this particulat code is not working.

here is my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/webapp_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>loginauth</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>login.LoginAuth</servlet-class>  

        <servlet-name>loginpage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>login.LoginPage</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>loginauth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loginauth</url-pattern>       

        <servlet-name>loginpage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loginpage</url-pattern>       
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you please provide jsp page and your servlets classes??

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the definitions in separate `servlet` and `servlet-mapping`elements:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginpage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>login.LoginPage</servlet-class>  
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginauth</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>login.LoginAuth</servlet-class>  
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginauth</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginauth</url-pattern>       
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginpage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginpage</url-pattern>       
</servlet-mapping>
```